# cURL Paypal IPN script not working

Tags: php, curl, paypal, paypal-ipn

I've been trying to figure out what's wrong with my ipn script. I've tried many different methods and I also tried fsockopen but I didnt get it working. Now I'm using cURL and it still isn't working. I've cURL installed and it should be working properly.

My script (Just a simple example, i removed some checks just for testing):

```
<?php
$ACTIVE_CONNECTION = mysql_connect('127.0.0.1', 'mysqluser', 'mysqlpassword') or die("Could not connect to server.");
mysql_select_db('mysqldb', $ACTIVE_CONNECTION) or die("Could not connect to database.");

$tid = $_GET['tx'];
$auth_token = "aqiopfsawdaisytrgkl";

$url = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";

$post_vars = "cmd=_notify-synch&tx=" . $tid . "&at=" . $auth_token;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_vars);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'cURL/PHP');

$fetched = curl_exec($ch);



$lines = explode("\n", $fetched);
$keyarray = array();
if (strcmp ($lines[0], "SUCCESS") == 0) {
for ($i=1; $i<count($lines);$i++){
list($key,$val) = explode("=", $lines[$i]);
$keyarray[urldecode($key)] = urldecode($val);
}
// check the payment_status is Completed
// check that txn_id has not been previously processed
// check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
// check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
// process payment
$payment_amount = $keyarray['mc_gross'];
$payment_status = $keyarray['payment_status'];
$payment_currency = $keyarray['mc_currency'];
$txn_id = $keyarray['txn_id'];
$receiver_email = $keyarray['receiver_email'];
$payer_email = $keyarray['payer_email'];
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($keyarray['custom']);

    if ($payment_status == 'Completed'){
            mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET vip = '1' WHERE `username` = '".$username."'");
        }
}
else if (strcmp ($lines[0], "FAIL") == 0) {
// manual investigation here
}
?>
```

Comment: Going to need more info than "it still isn't working."  What exactly is going wrong?  Are you getting invalid responses back from PayPal?  Is your script getting hit at all?

Comment: Agree with @Andrew Angell. "It still isn't working" isn't enough to go on.  What happens when you echo `$fetched`? If nothing is printed, is `$fetched` FALSE?  If so, what does `curl_error($ch)` tell you?

Comment: I tried that and $fetched printed "FAIL".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to test Sanbox IPN

https://developer.paypal.com/cgi-bin/devscr?cmd=_ipn-link-session

and

replace

```
if (strcmp ($lines[0], "SUCCESS") == 0) {
```

with

```
if (strcmp ($lines[0], "SUCCESS") == 0 || 1 == 1) {
```

Comment: If you're testing with the actual sandbox you don't have to use 1==1.  That would only be necessary if you're testing from your own form post and you wanted it to validate for testing purposes.  If the data is coming from the PayPal sandbox, though, it'll validate just fine.

Comment: Yes, you are right, this method is useful when you use the "external" tool "Sandbox IPN", please check the link that I sent to understand what I mean.